# How to use buildExpression in Swift 5.2 Function Builders?

Tags: swift, swift5

I understand that it's a [draft proposal](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/9992cf3c11c2d5e0ea20bee98657d93902d5b174/proposals/XXXX-function-builders.md). I tried to implement a simple DSL for building a string, like so:

```
@_functionBuilder
struct StringBuilder {
    static func buildExpression(_ string: String) -> [String] {
        [string]
    }
    static func buildBlock(_ children: [String]...) -> [String] {
        children.flatMap{ $0 }
    }
}

func s(separator: String = "", @StringBuilder _ makeString: () -> [String]) -> String {
    makeString().joined(separator: separator)
}

let z = s(separator: " ") {
   "this"
   "is"
   "cool"
}
```

However, the compiler complains that "'String' is not convertible to '[String]'". This leads me to believe that `buildBlock` is the only part of the proposal currently implemented. (This is understandable given that in SwiftUI they are building a hierarchy of views, so that's all they need.)

Is this correct or am I doing something wrong? What is the correct way to use `buildExpression`?

ielyamani's answer shows how to build a working string builder such as I used in my example above. However, that does not solve the actual problem. I'm not trying to build a string builder. I'm trying to figure out function builders. The string builder is just an example. For example, if we wish to have a string builder that accepts integers, we could in theory do the following:

```
@_functionBuilder
struct StringBuilder {
    static func buildExpression(_ int: Int) -> [String] {
        ["\(int)"]
    }

    // The rest of it implemented just as above
}
```

In this case, when the compiler encountered an `Int`, it would call `buildExpression` to then spit out our component type, in this case `[String]`. But as Martin R said in a comment to this question, `buildExpression` is not currently implemented.

Comment: See https://forums.swift.org/t/pitch-function-builders/25167/53: “Xcode 11 right now doesn't actually support buildExpression”

Comment: You may find it works better if you change this:

`static func buildBlock(_ children: String...) -> [String] {`

Note that I got rid of the `[` around `String` -- the `...` already makes it an array type.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered the same issue today, it seems that buildExpression isn't implemented. I ended up making a workaround by using a protocol "ComponentProtocol" and then creating "Expression: ComponentProtocol" and "Component: ComponentProtocol". That works for me for now. I am hoping it'll be implemented later.

```
protocol ComponentProtocol: ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral, ExpressibleByStringLiteral  {
    var value: String { get }
}

struct Expression: ComponentProtocol {
    let _value: String
    var value: String { _value }
    init(_ value: String) { _value = value }
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) { self.init(value) }
    init(stringLiteral  value: String) { self.init(value) }
    init<E: CustomStringConvertible>(_ value: E) {_value = String(describing: value) }
}

struct Component: ComponentProtocol {
    let _values: [String]
    var value: String { _values.joined(separator: ", ") }
    init(integerLiteral value: Int) { self.init(value) }
    init(stringLiteral  value: String) { self.init(value) }
    init<E: CustomStringConvertible>(_ value: E) { _values = [String(describing: value)] }
    init<T: ComponentProtocol>(_ values: T...) { _values = values.map { $0.value } }
    init<T: ComponentProtocol>(_ values: [T]) { _values = values.map { $0.value } }
}

@_functionBuilder struct StringReduceBuilder {
    static func buildBlock<T: ComponentProtocol>(_ components: T ...) -> Component { Component(components) }

    static func buildEither<T: ComponentProtocol>(first: T) -> Component { Component(first.value) }
    static func buildEither<T: ComponentProtocol>(second: T) -> Component { Component(second.value) }
    static func buildOptional<T: ComponentProtocol>(_ component: T?) -> Component? {
        component == nil ? nil : Component(component!.value)
    }
}

func stringsReduce (@StringReduceBuilder block: () -> Component) -> Component {
    return block()
}

let result = stringsReduce {
    Expression(3)
    "one"
    Expression(5)
    Expression("2")
    83
}

let s2 = stringsReduce {
    if .random () { // random value Bool
        Expression(11)
    } else {
        Expression("another one")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `buildBlock(_:)` takes a variadic number of arrays of strings, this would work:

```
let z = s(separator: " ") {
    ["this"]
    ["is"]
    ["cool"]
}
```

But that's still clunky. To take strings instead of Arrays of strings, add this function to `StringBuilder` which takes a variable number of strings:

```
static func buildBlock(_ strings: String...) -> [String] {
    Array(strings)
}
```

And now you can do this:

```
let z = s(separator: " ") {
    "Hello"
    "my"
    "friend!"
}

print(z)    //Hello my friend!
```

Comment: Sorry you went to the trouble to do this. I was already aware that I could do this. However, my goal is not to build a "string builder" DSL but to figure out the use of `buildExpression`. The string builder DSL was just an example. For example, in theory, we could use `buildExpression` to allow any string-convertible data type in our DSL, such as an integer, but that appears not to be possible at the moment.